# how to use javascript cleanTime in such case?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to clear the timeout and I couldn't figure how. I'm not sure what to pass on the clearTimeout method from window object... any tips?

```
                for (var k = 0; k <= arr2.length; k++) {

                  (function (k) {
                      window.setTimeout(function () {

                          //do something

                      }, 6000 * k);
                  })(k);

               }
```

Comment: by the way, I do need the "<="

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are creating `arr2.length` amount of timers, if you need "kill" a specific timer, you need an array of references.

```
//create a reference storage
var timerRefs = [];

for (var k = 0; k <= arr2.length; k++) {
    (function (k) {

        //reference the timeout to a variable
        var ref = window.setTimeout(function () {
            //do something
        }, 6000 * k);

        //store that reference in the array
        timerRefs.push(ref);
    })(k);
}
```

to clear a specific one, do:

```
clearTimeout(timerRefs[N]); //where N is the index of that timer
```

Comment: that's awesome, is there a way to find out all the open Timeout from the window object and release them? I'll apply your solution, but I'm just wondering, thanks

Comment: @EdwinSnts unless they are referenced in variables and you have access to the variables' scopes, I think you can't.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a timeout cancellable, you MUST capture its return value.

```
var myTimer = setTimeout(...);
```

Then, just pass that value to the function:

```
clearTimeout(myTimer);
```

---

Personally I would rewrite that:

```
(function(inp) {
    var k = 0, l = inp.length, timer;
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        // do something with inp[k];
        k++;
        if( k > l) clearInterval(timer);
    },6000);
})(arr2);
```

Some browser (Firefox in particular) react poorly to having too many timeouts running at once.